# How to load my angular app correctly with electron throu file:///?

Tags: angularjs, electron

I have a simple Angular app and it is in `www` folder of my project. It works ok in browser when I run it through http:// server or virtual host. But `index.js` loads this as file

```
mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/www/index.html');
```

So when I pun `electron .` it shows blank window. I tried to open my `index.html` in a Chrome browser through file:/// and it is also blank. The error in console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/Sergey/Sites/Electron-test/www/partials/layout.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10722

This is because on router ui

```
$stateProvider.state("app", {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'partials/layout.html'
});
```

There are some other same errors for images.

I guess there are 2 solutions to that.

1. Run server with node and change `loadUrl('file:///...')` to `loadUrl('http:///...')` but I have no idea how to do that.
2. Do something else. May be some header or parameter to allow cross origin requests and I have no idea how to do that.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your two options are related to each other, because CORS is a server configuration which can't be configured on `file:///`.  You should really research how to deploy a server, since it's generally good practice to replicate the environment you plan to host in on your development machine.  If you plan to host on a node server, then node in development is good (and easy); if you plan on using something else, like PHP, then set that up in your development environment, if possible.

Comment: This is AngularJS SPA app. It loads only static JS/CSS/HTML files. All requests for data is done to online JSON API server. So I guess any server will work.

Answer (score 6):

After some time i have figured out how to do this and now Electron builds app and it runs perfectly. Here is the whole `index.js` consumed by electron as starting point.

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

require('crash-reporter').start();

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if(process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });

    var server = http.createServer(requestHandler).listen(9527);

    mainWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:9527/index.html');
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        mainWindow.setTitle(app.getName());
    });
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
        server.close();
    });
});

function requestHandler(req, res) {
    var
        file    = req.url == '/' ? '/index.html' : req.url,
        root    = __dirname + '/www',
        page404 = root + '/404.html';

    getFile((root + file), res, page404);
};

function getFile(filePath, res, page404) {

    fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {
        if(exists) {
            fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, contents) {
                if(!err) {
                    res.end(contents);
                } else {
                    console.dir(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            fs.readFile(page404, function(err, contents) {
                if(!err) {
                    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    res.end(contents);
                } else {
                    console.dir(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

This is a starting point. All you have to do is change `root` parameter to indicate your `index.html` root folder. But I am sure if you build universal app, it is going to be `www`.

Comment: But this start up a http server, making the website available to the local network or even the whole world

Comment: Right. This is starting point. From here you can do anything. You can use special tocken inside your app and restrict access to local server to anyone without that token. I mean, there are so many ways to solve it once your app is running.

Comment: I notice this doesn't load files when people put `?name=var` querystrings

Comment: And how are you going to use it? You call your `index.html?var=name`? What is the pзгкзщыу,how do you get it in HTML and where do you use it?